# What is the best way to find files using Java 8?

Tags: java, file, java-8

I want to read files from a directory

Which all startswith (Example : like we have a list of startswith names)

- startsWith "abcd_"
- startsWith "Proto_"
- startsWith "foo_"
- startsWith "2020"
- startswith ....

  Another condition is endswith ".txt"

Now taking a scenario where in target directory, we have thousands of files.

So what is the efficient way to get all the files matched with said conditions.

**Note:Startswith is a dynamic list and the target directory, is getting loaded with lots of files every day , but will have one and only one corresponding file match at MAX ,even it is increasing in number of files **

I have wrote a prototype

```
Map<String,String> getFilesMap(Path path)    
{
Map<String, String> fatchedFileMap = new HashMap<>();
    
    List<String> fileNamePrefixes = getFileNamePrefixes();
    
   //Using File Filter implementation
    path.toFile().listFiles( (dir, fileName) -> {

        for (String fileNamePrefix : fileNamePrefixes) {
            if (fileName.endsWith (".txt") && fileName.startsWith(fileNamePrefix)))
             {
                fatchedFileMap.put(fileNamePrefix, fileName);
                return true;//does nothing 
            }
        }
        return false;//does nothing 
    });

    return fatchedFileMap;
}
```

This is giving me all the files whose name matches the prefixes (The provided list)

But looking for more better ways if any.

I don't want to introduce any third party lib,but still welcome to all solutions.

Comment: return true / false ?  you stop at the first file ?  You have some pattern on the file name ? like you can split name every "_" char or prefix is always n char long; suffix is the file suffix so after the last "."...

Comment: I would first debate the problem. A directory is not a database and should not be used for thousands of items that have to be sequentially searched. Windows has rapid wildcard-matching directory APIs, but this Java code cannot use them.

Comment: @wargre return true/false if for filter implemenations , actually i am adding the matched file names into a map.Name pattern is currentdate like xyz_yyyymmdd , and that is already handled in getFileNamePrefixes()

Comment: @user207421 , "Windows has rapid wildcard-matching directory APIs" what is that actually , and can i utilize using core java only

Comment: The purpose of `listFiles` is to return the filtered file array, not to perform additional operations in the filter and ignore the result. Besides that, you are repeating the `fileName.endsWith(".txt")` check for every prefix despite the result will never change during the loop. That’s especially wasteful when it evaluates to `false`, so you could skip the entire loop…

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you use [public String[] list​(FilenameFilter filter)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/File.html#list-java.io.FilenameFilter-) or [public File[] listFiles​(FileFilter filter)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles-java.io.FileFilter-) depending on your requirement.

Comment: as you can see i have already used the FileFilter Implementation with Lambda , can you write some piece of code with above stated requirement.